# Systemverilog property implication with or (||) is not working as expected?

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I am trying to write sytemverilog assertions for determining clock period(140MHz) with arbitrary + or - value of 0.001ns, here in this systemverilog property used "or" operator (||) for +/- deviations/changes of time periods but outputs are not as expected, can anyone explain what is the exact cause of this?, and for any value of clk_prd the assertion gets asserted which is not as expected, also please mention what is the optimal solution for this?

code snippet below,

```
module clock_gen();
    timeunit 1ns;
    timeprecision 100ps;  
    bit clk;
    realtime clk_prd =1000/340.0ns; //2.9411764
    //realtime clk_prd =1000/140.0ns; //7.1428571
    property SVA_clk(real clk_prd);
      time current_time;
      (('1,current_time=$realtime) |=> 
        (clk_prd <= $realtime-(current_time - 0.001ns)) ||
        (clk_prd >= $realtime-(current_time + 0.001ns))); 
    endproperty

    assert_period:assert property (@(posedge clk)SVA_clk(clk_prd))
      $display("clk pass : %0t ",$realtime); 
    else
      $warning("clk fail : %0t",$realtime);
    initial forever #7.1428 clk=!clk; 
    initial begin 
      repeat(15) @(posedge clk); 
      $finish; 
    end
    endmodule : clock_gen
```

Current output:

```
clk pass : 213 
clk pass : 355 
clk pass : 497 
clk pass : 639 
clk pass : 781 
clk pass : 923 
clk pass : 1065 
clk pass : 1207 
clk pass : 1349 
clk pass : 1491 
clk pass : 1633 
clk pass : 1775 
clk pass : 1917
```

Expected output

```
clk fail : 213 
clk fail : 355 
clk fail : 497 
clk fail : 639 
clk fail : 781 
clk fail : 923 
clk fail : 1065 
clk fail : 1207 
clk fail : 1349 
clk fail : 1491 
clk fail : 1633 
clk fail : 1775 
clk fail : 1917
```

(ref from [link](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/checking-clock-period-using-system-verilog-assertion))

Comment: i think that you messed up the logical expression. Are you checking for the difference be between `cllk_prd - 0.01` and `clk_prd + 0.01`?

Comment: @Serge This is to check the acceptable range of the clock to which it can deviate

Comment: Because #(7.1428ns/2) gets truncated by the timeprecision, which you had set to 0.1ns. (100ps)

Comment: Thanks much for the detail @dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a multitude problems with your code

1. The `timeprecision` should be in `1ps` for the code as written
2. `current_time` should be declared as `realtime`
3. Your clock generator period is 14.2, but you should have written `#(7.1428ns/2)`
4. You either have `+/-` reversed , or `<=/>=` reversed.

Comment: I still did not understand why timeprecision should be 1ps while required is 3 digit precision, could you please elaborate on this? and thanks for pointing the problems, by changing as per points 1,2,3(it shouldn't have been missed) and for 4th replaced or(||) with &&, after which its works as expected.

Comment: @Emman time is rounded to the precision of `timeprecision`. If set to 100ps, then 7.1428ns is rounded to 7.1ns. If set to 1ps, then 7.1428ns is rounded to 7.143ns. Your checker ls looking for a margin of ±0.001ns (aka ±1ps). Therefore your time precision must be 1ps or smaller.